# Is there a way to add s3 replication policy with existing bucket in cdk python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cdk

I am trying to add a s3 replication policy using cdk python. Its working fine if i create a new bucket.

But i want to do it using existing bucket. Is there a way to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can.

CDK code converts into CloudFormation. An `AWS::S3::Bucket` entity contains a `ReplicationConfiguration`.

There is no means for specifying a bucket in a `ReplicationConfiguration` -- it can only apply to the parent entity in the template, which would be a *new* S3 bucket.

CDK and CloudFormation templates are normally used to **deploy new infrastructure** rather than modify existing infrastructure.

As an alternative, you could write some code that calls the Amazon S3 APIs to activate replication.